# How do I adjust my website elements according using window width and window height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications, react-hooks

I have a grid(made using 2d array) in my web-app and its quite large. And it's not responsive and overlap other elements on small size screen. How do I set the set the number of row and number of columns of grid whenever the window size changes? I have tried but it only works if you refresh the page but I want it to be responsive so that Whenever I change screeen dimensions, grid dimensions should also change with it.
Check out the code below :

```
const ROWS=window.innerHeight;
const COLS=window.innerWidth;
const getIntialGrid = () => {
const newGrid = [];
for (let row = 0; row < Math.floor(ROWS/29); row++) {
  const currentRow = [];
  for (let col = 0; col < Math.floor(COLS/25); col++) {
    currentRow.push(createNode(col, row));
  }
  newGrid.push(currentRow);
}
//console.log(newGrid.length,newGrid[0].length);
return newGrid;
};

useEffect(() => {
const newGrid = getIntialGrid();
setGrid(newGrid);
 }, []);
```

Check out the demo [Here](https://amandhaka.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/). Try to resize your browser.

Comment: You can use resize observable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Comment: @demkovych Thanks for suggestion but I don't want to change dimensions of as in width and height of each cell in my gird I want to change number of cells in grid